# Who is affected when bypassing Perl safe signals?

Tags: perl, signals

Do the risks caused by bypassing Perl safe signals for example like shown in the [second timeout example](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Signal_Handling_and_Canceling_Operations) in the DBI documentation concern only the code that uses such bypassing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in that example works hard to localize the change to just that section of code, or any code called from it.

There is not 100% guarantee that no code will be effected outside the code that bypasses safe signals, because signals are no longer safe. In the example the call being timed out is a DBI->connect. For most DBD's this will be implemented mostly in C, unless the C code can handle being aborted and tried again you might find that some data structures internal to the DBD, or the libraries it uses, are left in a inconstant state.

The chances of the example code going wrong is probably incredibly tiny. My personal anecdote on the issues is that I had used the traditional Perl signal handling for years before safe signals were introduced and for a long time I had never had a problem. I hadn't even been very cautious about what I did in my signal handlers. Then we managed to hit a data set that actually did trigger memory corruptions in about 1 out of ever 100 runs. Just modifying the signal handlers to use better practices, similar to those in the example, eliminated our issues.

Comment: The question is not very good. I would like to know if a script with such a signal handling could affect for example other scripts/processes. I don't believe it but I still ask for security.

Answer (score 1):

What does that even mean? By using unsafe signals, you can corrupt Perl's internals and Perl variables. It can also cause problem if a non-reentrant C library call is interrupted.

This can lead to SEGFAULTs and other problems, and those may only manifest themselves outside the block where the timeout is in effect.

Comment: The question is not very good. I would like to know if a script with such a signal handling could affect for example other scripts/processes. I don't believe it but I still ask for security.

Comment: Not directly, no. It only changes that process's signal handling.